Solving linear system of equations with constraints on unknowns
I would like to solve a system of linear equations y=Uh for an unknown vector h, where I have a few constraints on some of the elements of $h$. The matrix U is composed of a vector u (length N) and a delayed version of it.
Let us consider a small example: y is a vector of size N corrupted by noise, U is a matrix of size $N \times 9$, where:
the 1st column of U is the vector u;
the 2nd column is one time step delayed vector u i.e. [0; u(1:end-1)];
the 3rd column is two time step delayed vector u i.e. [0; 0; u(1:end-2)];
the 4th column is a square of individual elements of 1st column;
the 5th column is a square of individual elements of 2nd column;
the 6th column is a square of individual elements of the 3rd column;
the 7th column is the product of individual elements of columns 1 and 2;
the 8th column is the product of individual elements of columns 1 and 3;
the 9th column is the product of individual elements of columns 2 and 3;

and $h$ is a vector of size $9$, where $N>9$. Here, I have few constraints on the vector $h$. If the first three elements are $a, b, c$, then the next three elements should be $pa^2, pb^2, pc^2$, where $p$ is a non-zero scaling factor. The last three elements should then be $2pab, 2pac, 2pbc$. How do I use such constraints on parameters using another parameter of an unknown vector? Could someone help me with this?
The solution h = pinv(U)*y does not guarantee the desired structure of h. How to ensure that the solution has this structure and it best approximates the true noisy output y? Here the unknowns are a,b,c,p.

Post it here.

Is p given or unknown?

The system is over-determined. How sure are you that there's an exact solution? (There probably isn't.) Are you attempting to do a least-squares fit?

This is not a linear system; it's a nonlinear system. Also, you must almost definitely adopt a weaker definition of solve, because the system is over-determined and so can only be solved in a least-squares sense. There are only three unknowns (a, b, c), and N>9 equations. By example,
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import least_squares


def make_h(abcp: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
    abc, (p,) = np.split(abcp, (-1,))
    a, b, c = abc

    # Here, I have few constraints on the vector $h$.
    return np.concatenate((
        # If the first three elements are $a, b, c$,
        abc,
        # then the next three elements should be $pa^2, pb^2, pc^2$.
        p*abc**2,
        # The last three elements should then be $2pab, 2pac, 2pbc$.
        (
            2*p*a*b,
            2*p*a*c,
            2*p*b*c,
        ),
    ))


def residuals(
    abcp: np.ndarray, U: np.ndarray, y: np.ndarray,
) -> np.ndarray:
    h = make_h(abcp)

    # I would like to solve a system of linear equations $y=Uh$ for an unknown vector $h$.
    yhat = U @ h
    return yhat - y


def solve(
    U: np.ndarray, y: np.ndarray,
) -> tuple[np.ndarray, np.ndarray]:
    M = U.shape[1]//3
    N = U.shape[0]
    result = least_squares(
        fun=residuals,
        args=(U, y),
        x0=np.ones(M + 1),
    )
    if not result.success:
        raise ValueError(result.message)

    return make_h(result.x), result.x


def main() -> None:
    rand = np.random.default_rng(seed=0)
    M = 3
    N = 20                        # $N>9$.
    u = rand.random(size=N)  # a vector u (length N)
    padded = np.concatenate((np.zeros(M - 1), u))
    delay = np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view(
        x=padded,
        window_shape=N,
    )[::-1, :]
    ua, ub, uc = delay
    U = np.vstack((
        delay, delay**2,
        ua*ub, ua*uc, ub*uc,
    )).T

    # Make some fake data that stand a chance of being solvable
    abcp_hidden = rand.random(size=M + 1)
    h_hidden = make_h(abcp_hidden)
    noise = rand.normal(size=N, scale=0.05)

    # $y$ is a vector of size $N$
    y = noise + U@h_hidden

    h, (*abc, p) = solve(U, y)
    print('h =', h)
    print('abc =', abc)
    print('p =', p)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

h = [2.70105108e-02 1.47198194e-01 6.76129121e-01 4.22152723e-04
 1.25374428e-02 2.64522905e-01 4.60118054e-03 2.11347169e-02
 1.15177095e-01]
abc = [0.02701051078001584, 0.14719819396169204, 0.6761291207038694]
p = 0.5786340691198476


Thank you for your response. I edited my question for more clarity. The matrix U is not random, but it has a specific structure. In fact, it is created from a vector u and its delayed versions. The scaling factor p is also unknown here. Yes the system is overdetermined, however I am looking for a solution that best approximates y and still has the desired structure of h.

I know that U isn't random, but you (have still) failed to provide a minimum reproducible example, so I had to fill in something. A minimum reproducible example must be able to run from start to finish after having copied-and-pasted.

Still: out of boredom, I'll edit this answer to demonstrate what U construction would look like.

I have measurements of y and u from a system, where the output y is noisy. These measurements are coming from a system that should ideally follow the mathematical model that I described, i.e. at time step k, the output y_k and input u_k are related as: y_k = au_k + bu_{k-1} + cu_{k-2} + p(au_k + bu_{k-1} + cu_{k-2} )^2. I am writing this equation as linear system of equation y = Uh for k = 1,...,N. and I have to find h. For now the solution h = pinv(U)*y does not provide the required structure of h. How do I enforce this?

Here you can assume u is a random vector, which is used to construct matrix U and y follows the mathematical model with prescribed a,b,c and p. Now noise is added to y and I would like to find the prescribed a, b, c and p using the noisy measurement y and matrix U

Thank you for the correction in your solution. The solution vector h deviates from the desired structure with increasing noise. This is because the 'solve' function uses Least square and does not constraint the required structure on the solution. Also, let's say I fix N = 1000, and I choose first 500 samples to create y as: y(1:500) = U(1:500,:)*h + noise1. Then I solve for h. With this h, I compute y(501:1000) using U(501:1000), then there is a significant deviation. This is typically the training and test dataset.

That's obvious. The only time that you can hope for an exact solution is for the exactly-determined or under-determined case. For realistic data your solution is guaranteed to be non-ideal other than in a least-squares sense.
